# Question of batch file with if condition "and" / "or" in cmd

Tags: windows, if-statement, batch-file, cmd

I would like to develop a batch file with the following condition:

1. Checking the DayOfWeek is whether equal to Mon - Fri --> **(True)** --> Copy ALL files --> **(False)** --> Go to check next condition
2. Checking the DayOfWeek is whether equal to Sat --> **(True)** --> Copy certain files --> **(False)** --> Go to check next condition
3. Checking the DayOfWeek is whether equal to Sun or public holiday --> Show an error message and exit

*(Remark: My idea is put those date of public holiday store to the text file and get value to check on it.)*

```
@ECHO OFF
FOR /F %%a IN ('Powershell -noP -c "(Get-Date).DayOfWeek.Value__"') DO SET week=%%a

IF %week% == "1" (GOTO ALLFOLDER) 
IF %week% == "2" (GOTO ALLFOLDER) 
IF %week% == "3" (GOTO ALLFOLDER)
IF %week% == "4" (GOTO ALLFOLDER)
IF %week% == "5" (GOTO ALLFOLDER)
IF %week% == "6" (GOTO CERTAINFOLDER)
IF %week% == "7" (ECHO ERROR! Script Exit!) EXIT(0)

ECHO Copying Files...
TIMEOUT /T 1 /NOBREAK > NUL
ECHO.
    
COPY C:\A.DAT E:\A.BAT
    
TIMEOUT /T 1 /NOBREAK > NUL

COPY C:\B.DAT E:\B.BAT
    
TIMEOUT /T 1 /NOBREAK > NUL

COPY C:\C.DAT E:\C.BAT
    
TIMEOUT /T 1 /NOBREAK > NUL

COPY C:\D.DAT E:\D.BAT
    
TIMEOUT /T 1 /NOBREAK > NUL
COPY C:\E.DAT E:\E.BAT

:ALLFOLDER
    ECHO Checking Folder....
    ECHO.

    IF EXIST %A% (

    ECHO A Folder Already Exists!
    ECHO.
    TIMEOUT /T 1 /NOBREAK > NUL

    ) ELSE (

    MKDIR %A%
    ECHO A Folder Created!
    ECHO.
    TIMEOUT /T 1 /NOBREAK > NUL

    )

    IF EXIST %B% (

    ECHO B Folder Already Exists!
    ECHO.
    TIMEOUT /T 1 /NOBREAK > NUL

    ) ELSE (

    MKDIR %B%
    ECHO B Folder Created!
    ECHO.
    TIMEOUT /T 1 /NOBREAK > NUL

    )

    IF EXIST %C% (

    ECHO C Folder Already Exists!
    ECHO.
    TIMEOUT /T 1 /NOBREAK > NUL

    ) ELSE (

    MKDIR %C%
    ECHO C Folder Created!
    ECHO.
    TIMEOUT /T 1 /NOBREAK > NUL

    )

    IF EXIST %D% (

    ECHO D Folder Already Exists!
    ECHO.
    TIMEOUT /T 1 /NOBREAK > NUL

    ) ELSE (

    MKDIR %D%
    ECHO D Folder Created!
    ECHO.
    TIMEOUT /T 1 /NOBREAK > NUL

    )

    IF EXIST %E% (

    ECHO E Folder Already Exists!
    ECHO.
    TIMEOUT /T 1 /NOBREAK > NUL

    ) ELSE (

    MKDIR %E%
    ECHO E Folder Created!
    ECHO.
    TIMEOUT /T 1 /NOBREAK > NUL
    
    )

    Powershell -noP -c "Write-Host 'INFO: Check Completed!' -ForegroundColor GREEN"
    TIMEOUT /T 2 /NOBREAK > NUL
    
:CERTAINFOLDER
    IF EXIST %A% (

    ECHO A Folder Already Exists!
    ECHO.
    TIMEOUT /T 1 /NOBREAK > NUL

    ) ELSE (

    MKDIR %A%
    ECHO A Folder Created!
    ECHO.
    TIMEOUT /T 1 /NOBREAK > NUL

    )

    IF EXIST %B% (

    ECHO B Folder Already Exists!
    ECHO.
    TIMEOUT /T 1 /NOBREAK > NUL

    ) ELSE (

    MKDIR %B%
    ECHO B Folder Created!
    ECHO.
    TIMEOUT /T 1 /NOBREAK > NUL
    
)

Powershell -noP -c "Write-Host 'INFO: Check Completed!' -ForegroundColor GREEN"
TIMEOUT /T 2 /NOBREAK > NUL
```

Thanks.

Comment: You don't need an and/or condition as such, the general method would be `@For /F %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoP "(Get-Date).DayOfWeek.Value__"') Do @If %%G Gtr 0 If %%G Equ 6 (Copy "CertainFiles") Else Copy "AllFiles"`. Adding additional public holidays on top of Sunday, _(`0`)_, either directly or from a separate file is a completely different question, unrealated to your main one, so I'll leave that to you to determine yourself.

Comment: You are doing a string comparison.  If quotes are on one side of the comparison, they must be on the other side of the comparison for it to ever evaluate to TRUE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another way to do it. The cmd interpreter can "GOTO" a label.

```
@ECHO OFF
FOR /F %%A IN ('powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command ^
    "@('sun', 'workday', 'workday', 'workday', 'workday', 'workday', 'sat')[$((Get-Date).DayOfWeek.Value__)]"') DO (SET "TARGET=%%~A")
GOTO %TARGET%

:sun
ECHO This is Sunday
GOTO TheEnd

:sat
ECHO This is Saturday
GOTO TheEnd

:workday
ECHO This is a workday
GOTO TheEnd

:TheEnd
EXIT /B
```

Answer (score -1):

Your logic is complicating things. I would do it this way:

1. If DayOfWeek = Sun or public holiday --> Show an error message and exit
2. If DayOfWeek = Sat --> Copy certain files and exit
3. Copy all other files